# Ext JS 4.1.3: Ext.Direct issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am having problems implementing Ext.Direct in my application. I have followed the tutorial in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/direct_grid_pt1), but not gotten it to work.

The problem with it is that it's always returning: `Invalid request` on all my calls for it, which would suggest that neither `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` nor `$_POST['extAction']` is set.

**router.php**

```
...
if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    $data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
} else if (isset($_POST['extAction'])) { // form post
    $isForm = true;
    $isUpload = $_POST['extUpload'] == 'true';
    $data = new Action();
    $data->action = $_POST['extAction'];
    $data->method = $_POST['extMethod'];
    $data->tid = isset($_POST['extTID']) ? $_POST['extTID'] : null; // not set for upload
    $data->data = array($_POST, $_FILES);
} else {
    die('Invalid request.');
}
...
```

**The POST values are as follows:**

```
{
    "action": "viewResourceParticulars",
    "method": "getResults",
    "data": [
        {
            "page": 1,
            "start": 0,
            "limit": 25,
            "group": [
                {
                    "property": "groupField",
                    "direction": "ASC"
                }
            ],
            "sort": [
                {
                    "property": "groupField",
                    "direction": "ASC"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "type": "rpc",
    "tid": 1
}
```

I have checked my php.ini and the `always_populate_raw_post_data` option is `true`, and it still does not work. So I am out of ideas at the moment.

Any help appreciated.

### Edit (2013-02-12 12:44):

The code used to call Ext.Direct:

**index.php**

```
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/direct/api.php');
```

**api.php return**

```
Ext.ns("Ext.app"); Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {"url":"js\/direct\/router.php","type":"remoting","actions":{"viewResourceParticulars":[{"name":"getResults","len":1}]}};
```

**Ext.data.Store**

```
...
proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    directFn: viewResourceParticulars.getResults
},
```

Comment: I can definitely help you solve it. But would need more info. Could you please show what bit of code exactly leads to your direct call?

Comment: I edited in some of the calls I use.

Comment: Everything in your edit seems to be fine. So I guess it's some sort of server issue. Could you try in `router.php` this: `$post = file_get_contents('php://input'); print_r( $post );` And see if you get anything there?

Comment: I believe I have found an answer to my own question. When I used the tutorial code it resulted in an error, but when downloading the working script code - it worked. I can't really determine any real difference between the two, and have no idea why one works and the other does not...

Comment: There are minor differences. Such as the use of `BogusAction` class instead of `Action`. And the `getResults` function calls for `__construct` instead of `OpenConnection` and it's `params` are defined as an object. Otherwise the code is exactly the same.